# Posting raw data to a WebAPI using JQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to work out how to post raw data to a webAPI using JQuery and Ajax, but I cannot seem to get the data to be sent across.

The endpoint works in Postman:
[image: Postman test]

Here is my rather simple JQuery:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: myUrl, data: ["21924"]});
```

What am I missing? This is not my usual area so I've had a good look through other questions, but non seem to quite fit! How do I recreate this Postman call via JQuery and Ajax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the data type and stringifying your data, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify(["21924"]),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){console.log(data);},
    failure: function(errMsg) {console.log(errMsg);}
});
```